# Restore all code to previous commit (which was before a merge)

Tags: git

Still understanding Git, so this may sound elementary. All I want to do is have all my code start back over to the commit `dfa7afd`, however this was before a merge shown below:

[image]

Also, this is what my GitBash is showing right now:

[image]

I am not exactly sure how I got one commit ahead of `origin/ticket-3`, but I just want to restore all my code to the `dfa7afd` commit. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOTE: This will reset ALL local modifications

```
git reset --hard <commit>
```

So, in your case:

```
git reset --hard dfa7afd
```

This will restore your repo to the commit specified